# Visual Studio 2013 Peek Definition feature doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

For some reason my VS 2013 Ultimate *Update 3* gives the following error with "peek definition" feature. I tried doing a clean install, that didn't help either. That's kinda annoying while developing. I found no web results about this, so I hope that's not just me in the entire world.

> **No results**
>
> We did not find any View Definition Results.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try following the steps in this blog post to debug devenv.exe (the VS process) and see if any first chance exceptions are being thrown when you attempt to do a "Peek Definition".  This will hopefully shed some light on what's going on.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2013/08/16/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-in-lightswitch.aspx

(Don't worry about the LightSwitch-ness of the post, the post could have been named "...in Visual Studio")